# Hanging chandelier with wire support

Tags: light-fixture, mounting

We're trying to install a chandelier and the instructions are generic (not for this specific light). I have hung chandeliers before but they always utilize the center threaded piece that holds the weight of the fixture.  This one came with a wire cable. How do I attach this? Should I loop it through the mounting bracket? I installed it without using the cable and then couldn't sleep as I imagined the chandelier crashing to the ground.  It was only being held up by the decorative screws on the canopy.  Is that enough?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would also be handy to know the weight of the chandelier. If not specified in the docs, jump, er... step on the scale with and without the chandelier in hand, subtract, post _just_ the chandelier's weight.

Comment: That center hole is not threaded like a normal light fixture. It’s a glass chandeliers. I would estimate at least 50lbs.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's long enough to do this but the thicker wire cable may be to "hang" the fixture while you connect the wires.

Answer (score 3):

Beautiful tin ceiling!

---

It's hard to tell from the pic, but I'd imagine that the rods hanging down from the gold-colored mounting plate are threaded and that they go through the holes on the canopy. If that's the case, then the acorn nuts being tightened against the canopy should be sufficient to hold this up.

- Even if the center threaded rod was long enough to thread through the center of the mounting plate, all the weight of the chandelier would be on that gold plate.
- With the canopy mounting screws taking the weight, the weight is still borne by that plate, but it is taken in two places instead of one, and the two spots are closer to the edge of the plate instead of in the center. This gives the weight a much shorter lever arm to attempt to bend things, thus making it more difficult.

About the only change I'd make would be to rotate the mounting plate clockwise a bit so that the support bolts are as close as reasonably possible to the screws that hold the plate to the box (i.e. you still have to get a screwdriver on there to tighten the plate to the box).

Comment: I would be concerned about the screws that the acorn nuts fasten to. If it was me I would put two nuts on those screws. One on each side of the plate and tighten the two nuts so the screw is locked into place at the right length. This way the screw won't turn when you tighten the acorn nuts.

Comment: I've actually used acorn nuts & bolts like this on wall-mounted lights before. I screw the bolts out a fair bit longer than needed, screw the acorns on tight, then keep screwing in until the acorns hit the canopy. That ensures the acorn is fully seated on the shaft, and that the shaft is as far in as it needs to be.